# Can I use python method without parentheses?

Tags: python, pandas, methods

I'm new to Python. I was using *head()* method to quickly check a  dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ['1', '3'], "b": ['1', '2'], "c": ['2', '4']})
df.head()
```

But I noticed that I can call it without parentheses too.

```
df.head
```

What's the difference with/without parentheses when using method? :(

Comment: The latter is a [*property*](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property).

Comment: You did this in a shell and it printed something out?

Comment: "But I noticed that I can call it without parentheses too" - no you can't. What you got when you tried that is not the head of the dataframe.

Comment: It just looked sort of like the right result at first glance because of how the method's `__repr__` embeds the `repr` of the dataframe.

Comment: `df.head` in a shell is the same thing as `print(df.head.__repr__())` in  a program.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa it is not a `property`

Comment: Oh, OK, so `df.head` is not really callable, then. I didn't check the pandas documentation and took the OP's statement as a fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

head return a method head() return the top 5(default) row in your dataframe

```
type(df.head)
<class 'method'>
type(df.head())
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```